# What is @reduxForm

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a React project and I don't understand this code

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
       
@reduxForm({
          form: EDIT_FORM,
          initialValues: {
            showLeadFromDescription: true,
            rssOptions: [],
            isHidden: 'true',
          },
        })
```

What is @reduxForm? How I can pass value like EDIT_FORM in @reduxForm?

Answer (score 0):

> What is @reduxForm?

You didn't share the imports section of the file, but judging from the name, I think it's the [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/) package.

BTW, don't use it in the new projects. It's not a good practice to use redux for form state management. You can use [Formik](https://formik.org/) or from the same author as "Redux Form", [React Final Form](https://final-form.org/react/)